# Add variables to external script

Tags: javascript

I have this script tag:

```
<script src="http://www.booking.tripfordog.com/SearchBox/274009" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it shows a search box as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/usainicola/7p7fka1b/

When i press "Cerca" a page with the results opens. I would like to filter those results with this variable:

```
?facilities=8
```

If i write the variable in the url of the newly opened page it works:

http://www.booking.tripfordog.com/Place/Cagliari_1.htm?facilities=8

the results are filtered.

The problem is that i would like the filter to be applied before opening the page so that the box always shows results that have the filter applied.

I wonder if this is even possible

Comment: Without changing the remote script, I highly doubt it.

Comment: Why don't you just redirect your page to the url with the filter applied?

Comment: @Bardo i would like to do it but there are other variables that depend on user choice (city, dates, etc)